# Why is the gate resistance of this PMOS so low? It should be very high

Tags: microcontroller, motor, power-electronics, pmos

I'm looking for PMOS with BJT
to drive a load (motor,) that is controlled by a microcontroller (IO_FET):

[image]

The motor needs three amperes of current.
I looked at the manufacturer's pages of the PMOS ([datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/62016/sq4401cey.pdf)) and I see the following parameter:

[image]

Shpuldn't the input resistance of the PMOS be a couple of MEGA/GIGA ohms?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384385/how-to-calculate-mosfet-internal-gate-resistance

Comment: @nanash1 I don't ask how to calculate the gate resistance, I'm asking how it makes sense that the gate resistance of mosfet is so low instead it should be so high, That was my question, your related question justifies my question, it 2 ohm in related question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gate resistance in this datasheet refers to the series resistance between the gate (pin) and the actual gate on the substrate.
This resistance is made up by the pin, bond wire, the substrate itself etc. Ideally this resistance should be 0 Ω, but in reality it's not.

Here is a simple drawing of a typical PMOS transistor model inside an actual package with bond wires and pins.
The gate resistance includes all it takes to charge up gate capacitance on the die.
[image: MOSFET drawing]

Gate resistance does not refer to the resistance from gate to source or drain, which should of course be close to infinite.

Comment: can you add to your answer the cross section of PMOS to understand your meaning between the gate pin and the actual gate on the substrate?

Comment: The pin itself has some length of thin wire/conductor which has some resistance, and then the internal interconnects from the gate pin to the actual gate electrode "plate" add their own resistance to this, which end up being fairly low.
Basically, this resistance is taken from the gate pin to the gate "plate" in the MOSFET.

Comment: @Knowledge Drew up a simple picture for you.

Comment: The general concept is correct, but discrete MOSFETs often use a different geometry to allow source and drain connections on opposite sides of the substrate.

Comment: @supercat You are right, but when drawing the picture I chose to use the most commonly known text book geometry for easy understanding, since the question was specifically regarding gate resistance and not overall MOSFET design.

Comment: It took me years to understand why discrete MOSFETs almost never have source and drain connections separate from the substrate, but those within ICs almost always do.  Moving one of the wires to the bottom of the chip, and adding a metal pad on top to connect one of the P regions to the N region should allow the diagram to be clear, while showing the reason for the P-N connection.